# Error calcular media de array en Java

Tags: java

Me encuentro con un código que acabo de realizar, pero me da una serie de error que no acabo de comprender.

El ejercicio me pide que calcule las notas medias de un array bidimensional pasado como parámetro. Por un lado tengo el código y por el otro tengo un archivo test.java donde va comprobando que los resultados sean correctos.

Aqui tengo mi codigo:

```
public static double[] averageGradeByStudent(double[][] notes) {
        //TODO
        double[][] mitjana = notes;
        double notasAlumnos = new double[8];
        double mediaAlumno = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < mitjana.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < mitjana[i].length; j++) {
                mediaAlumno += mitjana[i][j];
            }
            double result = mediaAlumno / mitjana[i].length;
            notasAlumnos.push(result);
            mediaAlumno = 0;
        }
        return notasAlumnos;
    }
```

Errores:

```
incompatible types: double[][] cannot be converted to double
double cannot be dereferenced
incompatible types: double cannot be converted to double[]
```

Tengo problemas de incompatibilidad con los doubles y no acabo de ver el porqué. Decir que estoy empezando y seguramente sean errores básicos.

Alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu código hay dos errores:

1. Al declarar `notasAlumnos` debes indicar que es un array, poniendo `[]` antes del nombre del objeto.
2. Para agregar el valor de `resultado` al array debes usar la notación: `nombreDelObjeto[indice]`, no `push`, pues no estamos en PHP o en Javascript... el método `push` no existe en Java.

Además de eso, lo puedes asignar directamente, así evitas el uso de memoria para crear el objeto `result`.

Así debería funcionar:

```
public static double[] averageGradeByStudent(double[][] notes) {
    //TODO
    double[][] mitjana = notes;
    double[] notasAlumnos = new double[8];
    double mediaAlumno = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < mitjana.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < mitjana[i].length; j++) {
            mediaAlumno += mitjana[i][j];
        }
        notasAlumnos[i]=mediaAlumno / mitjana[i].length;
        mediaAlumno = 0;
    }
    return notasAlumnos;
}
```

Comment: gracias! funciono!